# An error appears saying a function was referenced before it was assigned but only when I enter the year above 2005 or 2004

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 2
while x>1:
    from random import randint
    import time
    fn = input("Hello, what is your first name?")
    while any (ltr.isdigit() for ltr in fn):
        fn = input("Sorry an integer was entered, please try again")
    firstname = (fn[0].upper())
    ln = input("Hello, what is your last name?")
    while any (ltr.isdigit() for ltr in ln):
        ln = input("Sorry an integer was entered, please try again")
    lastname = (ln.lower())
    def main():
        dob = input("Please enter the year you were born")
        if dob > ("2005"):
            main()
        elif dob < ("2004"):
            main()
        else:
            def mob():
                if dob == ("2005"):
                    age = 11
                elif dob == ("2004"):
                    month = input("Please enter the first three letters of the month you were born")
                    while month not in ("Jan","JAN","jan","Feb","FEB","feb","Mar","MAR","mar","Apr","APR","apr","May","MAY","may","Jun","JUN","jun","Jul","JUL","jul","Aug","AUG","aug","Sep","SEP","sep","Oct","OCT","oct","Nov","NOV","nov","Dec","DEC","dec"):
                        month = input("Sorry that was incorrect, please enter the first three letters of the month you were born")
                    if month in ("Jan","JAN","jan","Feb","FEB","feb","Mar","MAR","mar","Apr","APR","apr","May","MAY","may","Jun","JUN","jun","Jul","JUL","jul"):
                        age = 12
                    elif month in ("Aug","AUG","aug"):
                        day = input("Please input the day you were born")
                        while day not in("31","30","29","28","27","26","25","24","23","22","21","20","19","18","17","16","15","14","13","12","11","10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1"):
                            day = input("Please input the day you were born")
                            if day == ("28","27","26","25","24","23","22","21","20","19","18","17","16","15","14","13","12","11","10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1"):
                                age = 12
                            elif day in ("29","30","31"):
                                age = 11
                        else:
                            age = 12
                    else:
                        age = 11
                else:
                    age = 11
                usernames = []
                age = int(age)
                age2 = age + randint(1,9)
                age2 = str(age2)
                print("Thank you for taking the time to enter your details, your username is now being generated")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Generating...")
                time.sleep(2)
                username = (dob[2]+''+dob[3]+''+firstname+''+lastname+''+age2)
                print("This is your username:" +''+username)
                usernames.append(username)
                age = str(age)
                with open("Import Usernames.txt", "w") as text_file:
                    print("The usernames are:   {}".format(usernames), file=text_file)
        mob()
    main()
```

An error only appears when I enter a year higher than 2005 or lower than 2004 but I don't know why, my question is, what have I done wrong?

This is the error that pops up:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mob' referenced before assignment

Comment: You are using functions as if they were GOTO labels. That is now how functions work. I suggest googling for some tutorials about functions. Anyway, the general idea is that you first define some functions on the top level, and then call them later. Do not nest functions inside functions of functions inside `for`, `while`, `if`, `else`blocks until you know what that does. Use the fact that functions can take arguments and return values.

Answer (score 0):

This whole programs is structured wrong...

Anyway, `mob` is declared only inside the `else` scope and is called right after the `if-elif-else` statements.
You should declare it in each these scopes, or right before them.

Beside that, I really suggest you read about [Python identation](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html).

Comment: Sorry, yeah I should probably read up on indentation which I will, thanks for the link and help